# How to get xshift to work on scope

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to xshift a whole block of tikz drawings and have this setup:

```
%
% Document.
%

\documentclass[10pt,halfline,a4paper]{index}

%
% Packages.
%

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

%
% Document start.
%

\begin{document}

%
% Header.
%

\title{Demo}

%
% Abstract.
%

\abstract{Demo. \cite{foo}}

\maketitle

%
% Introduction.
%

\section{Introduction}

Hello
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \demoscopedcircle{5}{xshift=3cm}
\end{tikzpicture}
World

%
% Conclusion.
%

\section{Conclusion}

%
% References.
%

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{./index}


%
% Appendix.
%

\appendix

\end{document}
```

With class file:

```
%
% Set latex version.
%

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2018/03/16 Demo Latex]

%
% Expose `index`.
%

\ProvidesClass{./index}

%
% Configure.
%

\DeclareOption{oneline}{\PassOptionsToPackage{doublespacing}{setspace}}
\DeclareOption{halfline}{\PassOptionsToPackage{onehalfspacing}{setspace}}
\DeclareOption{endnotes}{\ProvidesPackage{endnotes}\note@endtrue}
\DeclareOption{numbib}{\num@bibtrue}
\DeclareOption{nonumbib}{\num@bibfalse}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass{article}

%
% Import packages.
%

\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
\RequirePackage{verbatim}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{endnotes}
\RequirePackage[left=.7in,right=.7in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{xspace}
\RequirePackage{amscd}
\RequirePackage{rotating}
\RequirePackage{latexsym}
\RequirePackage{multicol}
\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{algorithm}
\RequirePackage{subfigure}
\RequirePackage[hyphens,obeyspaces]{url}

\newcommand\demosquare[1]{\tikz{\filldraw[draw=#1,fill=#1] (0,0) rectangle (0.2cm, 0.2cm);}}
\newcommand\demotriangle[1]{\tikz{\filldraw[draw=#1,fill=#1] (0,0) -- (0.2cm,0) -- (0.1cm,0.2cm);}}
\newcommand\democircle[1]{\tikz{\filldraw[draw=#1,fill=#1] (0,0) circle [radius=0.1cm];}}

\newcommand\demoscopedcircle[2][]{
  \begin{scope}[#1]
    \democircle{red}
  \end{scope}
}


\newcommand\demovspace[1]{
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#1} {
    \hfill \break
  }
}

%
% Define `abstract`.
%

\let \@abstract \relax
\long \gdef \abstract#1{{%
  \gdef \@abstract{%
    \small%
    \begin{center}{%
      \bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}%
    }\end{center}%
    {\quotation%
    \noindent#1%
    \endquotation}%
    \par%
}}}

%
% Define `author`.
%

\def \author#1 {%
  \def \and{\\}%
  \gdef \@author{#1}%
}

%
% Make title.
%

\def \@maketitle {%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  {\leftskip\z@ plus 1fill\rightskip\leftskip
        \let \footnote \thanks
        {\LARGE \noindent\@title \par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \noindent\@date}%
    \vskip 2em%
        \@abstract%
    \vskip0em
  \par}
  \vskip 1.5em}
```

The key lines are:

```
\newcommand\demoscopedcircle[2][]{
  \begin{scope}[#1]
    \democircle{red}
  \end{scope}
}
```

and

```
Hello
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \demoscopedcircle{5}{xshift=10cm}
\end{tikzpicture}
World
```

I would just like the `xshift` to move the circle, and have it be configurable from the outside on the `\demoscopedcircle` macro.

Comment: Your `\demoscopedcircle` takes one optional argument and one required argument. The optional argument has an empty value. The required argument is never used. `\demoscopedcircle[xshift=10cm]{}` is going to do what you want (except that the second argument is useless).

Comment: Using a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem would help. You included a lot of unnecessary code.

Comment: Sorry, I am still working on getting a minimal working example up and running, I started from a bulky project. Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scope is shifted, but you can't see it unless you put something else in the `tikzpicture` to compare from what it is shifted off (even a transparent thing is enought).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\democircle}[1]{\filldraw[#1] circle [radius=0.1cm];}

\newcommand{\demoscopedcircle}[2][]{
  \begin{scope}[#1]
    \democircle{#2}
  \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}

Hello
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \demoscopedcircle[xshift=10cm]{red}
\end{tikzpicture}
World

Hello
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \fill circle (1pt) ;
  \demoscopedcircle[xshift=10cm]{red}
\end{tikzpicture}
World

Hello
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \fill[opacity=0] circle (1pt) ;
  \demoscopedcircle[xshift=10cm]{red}
\end{tikzpicture}
World

\end{document}
```